# I am trying to generate pdf in flutter application using " Pdf creation library". While generating pdf in other language it gives exception

Tags: android, pdf, flutter, dart

**This is the code using to generate pdf in other languages font:**

```
final Uint8List fontData = File('fonts/shivaji05.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
final ttf = Font.ttf(fontData.buffer.asByteData());
```

**This is how I am using the defined font in the text:**

```
Text('साई बाबा', textScaleFactor: 2, style: new TextStyle(font: ttf)),
```

**Error log**

```
E/flutter (26251): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:pdf/src/font.dart': Failed assertion: line 145 pos 14: 'false': 
E/flutter (26251): ---------------------------------------------
E/flutter (26251): Can not decode the string to Latin1.
E/flutter (26251): This font does not support Unicode characters.
E/flutter (26251): If you want to use strings other than Latin strings, use a TrueType (TTF) font instead.</i>
```

Comment: "This font does not support Unicode characters." is the problem. Use a font that supports the characters you need.

Comment: I tried many fonts which support for Marathi language but none of them worked..but thanks for the suggestion @Henry, I will keep trying

Comment: Couldn't be able to solve this problem, finally, I used [flutter_html_to_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_to_pdf) plugin which worked very well with any kind of language.

Answer (score 5):

I have had similar error when am trying to generate pdf in flutter application using “ Pdf creation library”. While generating pdf have right single quotation mark " ’ " "&#8217" in my source text.

**Code with error**

```
final String soutceString = 'My source text with " ’ "';

final Document pdf = Document(deflate: zlib.encode);

pdf.addPage(
    MultiPage(
       build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
            Paragraph(text: soutceString),
       ]
    )
);
```

**Error log**

```
flutter: 'package:pdf/src/font.dart': Failed assertion: line 145 pos 14: 'false':
---------------------------------------------
Can not decode the string to Latin1.
This font does not support Unicode characters.
If you want to use strings other than Latin strings, use a TrueType (TTF) font instead.
```

When I found wrong symbol  I just replace it.

**Code with fast fix**

```
final String sourceString = 'My source text with " ’ "';

final Document pdf = Document(deflate: zlib.encode);

sourceString.replaceAll('’', '`'),

pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
   build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
            Paragraph(text: sourceString)
        ]
    )
);
```

But I was afraid, of new wrong symbol come in future. I **added arial.ttf fonts in to assets** (arial.ttf contain my symbol) and use it. [Adding assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-imageshttps://)

**Best case for me**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;



final String sourceString = 'My source text with " ’ "';

final Document pdf = Document(deflate: zlib.encode);

pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
     theme: Theme.withFont(
        base: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/arial.ttf")),
        bold: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/arial.ttf")),
        italic: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/arial.ttf")),
        boldItalic: Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/arial.ttf")),
      ),
   build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
            Paragraph(text: sourceString)
          ]
    )
);
```

Comment: This solution worked indeed. You can read [Custom fonts in flutter tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) to insert the arial font in your project

Comment: API changed rename Theme.withFont to ThemeData.with...